# How does making the conducting wires tight help current flow?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electric-fields, electrical-resistance

I have read most of the times that when performing activities with electric current and its effects **the wire in the circuit should be in tension**. But I never got the reason behind it.

So, *How does it help current flow ? Why does it even matter ? Does resistance increase when wire is not in tension but loose ?*

---

Again I would like to add that by **tension** I mean to say that the wire is straight and not in curved shape. The word is similar to what we use for the ropes in Newtonian mechanics.

Comment: To assure that the current actually flows. Quite a lot of electric mulfunctioning can be traced to faulty contacts.

Comment: @Vadim does it have any other relevance ?

Comment: I don't think so. But *mulfunctioning* in this case means not only the equipment not working, but also spark, which psoes a danger of fire, faster wear, etc. I have heard old-school repairment complaining that these days they rush to replace a whole piece (like a screen in a car) for a hefty price, whereas the problem could often be fixed by simply cleaning the contacts or doing a bit of soldering.

Comment: @Vadim now I understood why you raised this point . It was my typing and grammatical error . Edited ;)

Comment: In some countries *tension* is what the USA calls *voltage*.  Do you mean the word as a force or as a voltage?

Comment: @garyp it would appear a third definition is meant - see JohnMeyer's answer

Comment: @garyp by tension I meant what we mean for strings in Newtonian mechanics.. I hadn't expected these much of confusions with words :)

Answer (score 3):

I read your question to mean that you believe that the wire between two terminals should be in tension. That is not the intention of the statement you have in bold.

The intention is that the terminal is tight to the wire so that a good connection is ensured.

The terminal is tight not the wire.

Comment: yes I meant to say that the wire should be in tension . Just a typing mistake.. and some grammatical errors .. edited thanks :)

Comment: Interesting - over here in the USA I've never heard the word "tension" used to describe a solid connection point.  Is that a common definition elsewhere?

Comment: they edited what was written in bold. it used to say something to the effect of "the wire should be connected to the terminal tightly"

Comment: @JohnMeyer by tension I meant what we meant for strings in Newtonian mechanics..

Comment: @JohnMeyer by tension I meant what we meant for strings in Newtonian mechanics..

Comment: typically, there is no reason to have the wire under tension. the difference in resistance is negligible (a function of the length, diameter, and material of the wire).

Answer (score 0):

The wire is made tight so that they don't hang down too much to make a contact with eachother resulting in a short circuit. And sometimes there's a probability of a fire too.

To add to this point, these tightening of wires have got something to do with the climate too. That is, if you don't make the wire tight enough during the winter, the wires will expand (linear expansion) and hang down too much during the summer. This will create those nuisances mentioned above. On the other hand, if it's the summer season, when they're placing the wires, they'll hang the wires down loose, so that the wires don't contract too much and break during the winter.

Comment: not correct in any situation I can think of

Comment: Could you please explain what you meant?